# Trouble with BufferedImage & ImageObserver in Clojure/Swing/Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, clojure

I've been trying for hours to get my drawing method to work by drawing in a BufferedImage stored in a Clojure `ref`, and then to have that painted onto the component (in this case a `JPanel`) in order to display it. Unfortunately, this isn't working well at all.

My code is this (pared down, but showing the relevant parts:

```
(defn create-graph
  "Data-ref is [xs ys], buffered-image-ref holds the basic graph."
  [data-ref buffered-image-ref & {:keys [width height image]}]
  (proxy [JPanel]
      []
    (getPreferredSize [] (Dimension. width  height))
    (paintComponent [g]
                    (proxy-super paintComponent g)
                    (if-not @buffered-image-ref
                      (dosync
                       (ref-set buffered-image-ref
                                (xy-plot2
                                 (first @data-ref)
                                 (second @data-ref)
                                 (.getGraphics
                                  (BufferedImage. width height 
                                                  BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_ARGB))
                                 :axis? true
                                 :width width
                                 :height height))))
                    (.drawImage g @buffered-image-ref
                                0 0 
                                (proxy [ImageObserver]
                                         []
                                       (imageUpdate []
                                          (proxy-super imageUpdate)))))))
```

And, below, xy-plot2 (which doesn't appear to be the problem, but I'll include it for completeness:

```
(defn xy-plot2
  "Draws an xy-plot in the given Graphics context.
   'xs must be equal in length to 'ys."
  [xs ys gfx
   & {:keys [color max-y axis? y-buffer width height]
     :or {color Color/RED y-buffer 0}}]
  (let [h (/ height 2) ;; since we have -h to h (not 0 to h)
        w width ;; since we graph 0 to w
        len (count xs)
        min-x (apply min xs)
        xs (if-not (zero? min-x)
             (map #(- % min-x) xs)
             xs)
        max-y (or max-y (apply max ys))
        max-x (apply max xs)]
    (.setColor gfx color)
    (dorun ;; this is the key part, along with scale-xs and draw-l
     (take len
           (iterate (partial d-line gfx h)
                    [(scale-xs xs w 0)
                     (scale-xs ys h y-buffer)])))
    (and axis? (or (.setColor gfx Color/BLACK) (.drawLine gfx 0 h w h)))
    gfx))
```

When I run this, I get this error, which leads to to believe I've messed up in the last part of the `paintComponent()` method.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
No matching method found: drawImage for class sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D
```

I've tried substituting `nil` for the `ImageObserver`, but to no avail. I've tried other arg orders (for other `drawImage` methods for other types of `Graphics` classes). All to no avail.

Sorry if I'm sounding a bit hard to understand, this bug's been plaguing me. I'll edit in the morning, if need be!

Thank you so, so much, 
Isaac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ***buffered-image-ref*** is set to the graphics of the **BufferedImage**, not the image itself.

Comment: That was it. Good god. Is there a medicine to help this? Also, you one of those who wanted the cookies offered? :) Thanks so much, I have bad code reviewing skills apparently.